# absolute fastest way to zip (not compress) larger files in 7zip?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, speed, archiving

I need to know the absolute fastest way to zip (not compress) larger files in 7-Zip.

By large files I mean 1Tb or so, this will be done often (multiple times per day).

I tried WinZip because it has GPU support and I have a decent GPU in my system and 7-Zip still smoked it. I have it set to Store I.E. no compression just basically "Zip". Also, I set the priority to Realtime in the task manager (which also helped a bit).

Still, it's not fast ENOUGH.

I was looking into buying a PCIe compression device but

1. I have zero experience with them.
2. Will it even work on 7-Zip?
3. Will it outperform the i7 9900k I'm currently using?

like a HP PCI-E Hardware Compression 441667-001 AG306-60001 9000 for example

Comment: If you do not want to compress then you don't need much computing power (CPU/GPU). You need throughput from your disks, RAM (and from your network in case you access or transmit the files via network). What exactly do you want to achieve? A copy/archive from what storage to what storage? Via what channel? How fast would be fast enough?

Comment: As Kamil says simply *storing* files without compression needs nearly no CPU or GPU power, and is 100% reliant on your storage devices. Using a GPU in that case would be expected to be slower as you are copying data to and from the PCIe bus as well as to and from whatever storage devices you have. If you are using "no compression" then why do you think a PCIe compression card will help?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what a "PCIe compression device" is.  Could you [edit] your question and clarify that fact?

Comment: The fastest NVMe(?) SSD you can afford would be a good start

Comment: @Ramhound My guess would be https://www.silicom-usa.com/pr/server-adapters/encryption-compression-offload-server-adapters/encryption-compression-intel-server-adapters/pe316is2lbclb-crypto-compression-intel-based/ & https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/network-io/ethernet/10-25-40-gigabit-adapters/quickassist-adapter-for-servers.html

Comment: and not compressing doesn't mean it'll be faster. Many modern algorithms are so fast that even the fastest SSDs are slower. For example lz4 and zstd can achieve GBs/second and probably saturates RAM bandwidth with better CPUs/GPUs. It significantly reduces the IO throughput requirements

Comment: So at Store, full bore, i7 9900k CPU and a M.2, how fast SHOULD a 1TB file take? ball park in everyones opinion?

Comment: @Stugots2 `copy file.txt file2.txt` should take about the same time as `7z a -mx0 file.7z file.txt`. My laptop SSD averages around 150MB/s (read+write), so 1TB takes about 2 minutes if nothing else is running. 7z runs slightly slower

Answer (score 1):

Using the 7-Zip File Manager GUI, in the *Add File* dialog, select *0 - Store* as compression level - zips as fast as your storage can go, without compression.

On the command line, use the `-mx0` option, e.g. `7z a -mx0 archive.7z testfile.bin`